# php question about scope

Tags: php, scope

i've been thinking if something like this is possible.

```
// this creates a variable $test in the scope it was called from
function create_var() {}

class A {
  function test()
  {
    create_var();
    // now we have a local to var() method variable $test
    echo $test;
  }
}
```

So, the question is, can a function create_var() create a variable outside of its scope, but not in a global scope? Example would be the extract() function - it takes an array and creates variables in the scope it was called from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible. It's possible only to access the global scope from within a function.

You could make `create_var()` return an associative array. You could `extract()` that in your function:

```
function create_var() 
 { return array("var1" => "value1", "var2" => "value2"); }

class A {
function test()
{
    extract(create_var());
    // now we have a local to var() method variable $test
    echo $test;
}
}
```

Something a bit closer to what you want to do is possible in PHP 5.3 using the new [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) feature. That requires declaring the variables beforehand, though, so it doesn't really apply. The same goes for passing variable references to `create_var()`: `create_var(&$variable1, &$variable2, &$variable3....)`

**A word of warning**: I can think of no situation where any of this would be the best coding practice. Be careful when using `extract()` because of the indiscriminate importing of variables that it performs. It is mostly better to work without it.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i knew all that, i was just secretly hoping it was possible. Well, i wouldn't use it with extract, i basically needed a function to extract some of the parameters, comming from POST or GET or whatever. And since i only want to allow extract() to play with some specific variables in these arrays, the easiest solution is like you provided. But still, would be nice if i could just do something like: extractvars('field1,field2,field3'), because things like that simply look more clean to me than a bunch of array stuff ;]